# TYPO3 fal_securedownload Slot

Tags: typo3, signals-slots

I`m using fal_securedownload 1.1.0 and TYPO3 7.6.12 and i want to log the downloads via the Slot BeforeFileDump.

In my Extension I have a `ext_localconf.php` contents this:

```
<?php
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher $signalSlotDispatcher */

$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\SignalSlot\\Dispatcher');


$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
        'BeechIt\\FalSecuredownload\\Hooks\\FileDumpHook',
        'BeforeFileDump',
        'MyVendor\\MyExtension\\Slot\\LogFileDump',
        'logFileDump'
);

?>
```

and in Classes/Slot i have a LogFileDump.php contents this:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExtension\Slot;

/**
 * Class LogFileDump
 * @package MyVendor\MyExtension\Slot
 */

class LogFileDump {
    public function logFileDump($file,$this) {
        var_dump($file);
        var_dump($this);
    }
}
?>
```

When I test this I got the Error:

> The given class "MyVendor\MyExtension\Slot\CallUrl" is not a
>   registered object.

Why I thought TYPO3 loads my Class automatically because of the namespace.

Did anybody has an Idea what's wrong with my Code

Comment: Have you tried to clear typo3temp directory and all other cache and double checked your naming conventions?

Comment: yes i did. My Solution was to put a composer.json into my Extension Directory. This loads the Classes correctly.

Comment: @BeP.Ier you might want to create a self-answer, so that it is not lost in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was to put a composer.json into my Extension Directory. This loads the Classes correctly